# How do you handle jira version and maven versionning of your project in a promotion base ci environment

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, version, jira

In our company, we currently have 5 environments

1. Local : developer's computer
2. Integration : server available to all developers in order to gather developments of the next version and validate them
3. Functional : Available to our product owner so that he can assert that the features he requested are okay
4. Benchmarks : In order to assert that we didn't add regressions in performance
5. Production : Finally !

Our deployment strategy is based on promotions : when we want to deliver a current build, we perform a release and we deliver it on the functional env (3). If it is validated, we promote the same bundle to the benchamrks env (4) and if everything is ok, it's promoted to production (5)

We are currently trying to manage the features in our Jira dashboard with version management.
For instance, we are targetting next release for version 2.0.0.

So imagine we reach the end of our devs. We were working on a 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT bundle. This bundle was available locally (1) and on our integration environment (2).
In order to deliver our devs to functional and benchmarks env, we perform a release 2.0.0.
If any issue is identified on these environments, it means we need to deploy a fix and so we need to deploy a 2.0.1 release. Maybe we missed so many things that we are finally able to promote our bundle to production with version 2.0.52.

Here, we have an issue : Jira was targetting version 2.0.0 while we delivered a version 2.0.52.

Our first solution is to use rc qualifier. It means we would have reached and delivered in production the version 2.0.0-rc52. But it does not look ok for us since it is still a "release candidate" and not a release.
The other solution is to deliver 2.0.0-rc52 to our benchmark environment (4). Since this bundle is validated and our PO wants it on production, we perform a new release from our 2.0.0-rc52 tag to deliver the 2.0.0 bundle to production. But we break our promotion system and we introduce a risk by generating a different bundle from our 2.0.0-rc52.

We feel like we are missing something. What do you do ? Did you encounter this version issues ? How did you handle this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible approaches I can think of:

1. You only manage the first two parts of your version in the Jira ticket (like `2.0`), so you can easily adapt the bugfix number. This requires that you raise the second number every time you do a new planning.
2. You always change the number in the Jira ticket when a new version gets deployed. This can be done through REST, so that you avoid manual mistakes.